# Autocomplete Jquery dataSource with JSON

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using the autocomplete widget of JQuery using JSON to parsed the db information but doesn't work. There are lots of questions like mine but I've not been able to find a solution. My php file with JSON parsed is this:

This error appears in a browser console, in first line of php:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

The php file `peliculas.php`

```
<?php

    function makeSqlConnection()
    {
        $SERVIDOR_MYSQL = "localhost";
        $BASE_DATOS = "db";
        $USUARIO_MYSQL = "root";
        $PASSWORD_MYSQL = "";

        $con = mysql_connect($SERVIDOR_MYSQL,$USUARIO_MYSQL,$PASSWORD_MYSQL) or die(mysql_error()); 
        mysql_select_db($BASE_DATOS,$con) or die(mysql_error());
        return $con;
    }

    function disconnectSqlConnection($con)
    {
        mysql_close($con);
    }

    $con = makeSqlConnection();

    $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT PYS_STR, PYS_TITULO FROM pys WHERE PYS_STR LIKE '%".$term."%';", $con);

    $informacion = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        array_push($informacion, array('label' => $row['PYS_TITULO'], 'value' => $row['PYS_STR']));
    }

    echo json_encode($informacion);
?>
```

JSON returns this:
`[{"label":"Reservoir Dogs","value":"reservoirdogs"},{"label":"Machete","value":"machete"},{"label":"Wall Street","value":"wallstreet"},{"label":"Django Desencadenado","value":"djangodesencadenado"},{"label":"The Wire","value":"thewire"},{"label":"This Is England '88","value":"thisisengland88"}]`

This is my script:

```
$(function() {    
        $( "#peliculas" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/bundles/pys/php/peliculas.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {terms: request.term},
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.value
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
            },
            close: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
            }
        });
    });
```

and this is my html code:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="peliculas">Peliculas: </label>
  <input id="peliculas" />
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top: 2em; font-family: Arial;">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

## SOLUTION

I've solved the error. The problem was in the location of `peliculas.php`; Symfony2 was detecting this php file like js file in the `/resource/public/js` directory. When I've changed the php file to a new directory and I've updated the `url` parameter in the script, it has worked fine.

The second problem was in the `data`parameter:

`data: {terms: request.term},` when I replaced `terms` with `term` the filtering worked fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work." Are there errors on the page?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker JSON returns fine and JS is very similar to JQuery autocomplete example. When I write into label does not appear anything. I don't know what is wrong, perhaps in `$.ajax(...` or perhaps something is missing in PHP... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not working as expected because **comma** is missing

```
label: item.label,
value: item.value
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, but the result is the same, when I write in the text label nothing appears. Thanks for the reply!!

Comment: Are you able to see any message/warning in console. You can try `console.log('label = '+item.label+' value = '+item.value)` and check if `AJAX`call is returning the data

Comment: I have this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in the first line of php; in `<?php`. It crashes on "peliculas.php", so fails to enter in "success"

Comment: @benatespina PHP code seems correct to me. Are you getting same `ERROR` if you call PHP page directly in browser like `http://<path to file>/peliculas.php`? ...

Comment: Yeah, the problem was in the php file location. I've solved it. But now I have another question to filtering the data. I've modified the php file with the term argument (I have just updated the question code) but something is wrong or something is missing because doesn't filtering. If I use the browser url with `my host/bundles/pys/php/peliculas.php?term=`the filter works fine but with AJAX call no. I believe that the error is in the script but I don't know.

Comment: Are you getting `ZERO/ALL` records with Ajax? Are you able to see the `term` parameter for ajax request

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new in this and I don't understand what are you saying me... With this code the autocomplete doesn't return any record, if I updated the url parameter with `url: "/bundles/pys/php/peliculas.php?term=",` the function returns all records but without filtering.

Comment: I think you need to replace `data: {terms: request.term},` with `data: {term: request.term},` see the difference between **terms** and **term**

Comment: Thanks!! Yeah, I've just changed this, and it has worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1) Please check your editor if it automatically inserts a Unicode Signature (BOM) in your files.
http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark#detect

You may have a BOM (byte-order-mark) character at the beginning of your php file `peliculas.php` that causes problems to the output.

*Quick fix for this if you cant find setting to remove BOM: 
Copy - Paste all the contents of your php file to an empty file in [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), and save the file as UTF-8 (notepad++ does not write BOM)*

2) add the application/json header before the json_encode

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($informacion);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've done what you say, but the same error appears. :(